# Is there a way to print dictionary keys and respective list of values on my django based app?

Tags: django, python-3.x, dictionary, django-templates

Can Anyone answer this,
This is my maketest.html
Iam trying to print a dictionary with keys and respective list of values,
Is there a module or a backend or function in django that can perform something like this?

Is there a solution to this problem in python?

```
{% extends 'TakeTestApp/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h3 class="display-6">{{ TestName }}</h3>
    <article class="media content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
                <p class="display-6">
                    {% for q in quesBank %}
                        {{ q  }}
                        {{ quesBank[q] }}
                    {% endfor %}

                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
{% endblock content%}
```

This is my ques.txt,

```
Q: What is your name?
opt1:Vineeth*
opt2:Vineth
opt3:Vinith
opt4:Vinth

Q: Where are u from?
opt1:Hyderabad
opt2:Secunderabad*
opt3:Rajasthan
opt4:vizag

Q: What is the capital of india?
opt1:* Delhi
opt2: Telangana
opt3: Madhya Pradesh
opt4: Gujrat

Q: What is 2+1?
opt1: 0
opt2: 1
opt3:* 3
opt4: 6
Q: Python is a _____ language
opt1: Markup
opt2: not
opt3:* programming
opt4: English
```

and my views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from Test.forms import TestForm

# Create your views here.


def MakeTest(request):
    file1 = open('ques.txt', 'r')
    lines = file1.readlines()
    file1.close()
    ques = []
    options = []
    ans = []
    for line in lines:
        if "Q:" in line:
            ques.append(line)
        if "opt" in line:
            options.append(line.replace('*', ''))
        if "*" in line:
            ans.append(line)
    i = 0
    quesBank = {}
    for qu in ques:
        quesBank[qu] = [options[x] for x in range(i, i + 4)]
        i = i + 4
    return render(request, 'TestMaking/maketest.html', {'TestName': 'Test Make App', 'ques': ques, 'options': options, 'quesBank': quesBank})
```

This is what i tried, but couldnt get my required output

I expect the output as,

```
Q: What is your name?
opt1:Vineeth
opt2:Vineth
opt3:Vinith
opt4:Vinth

Q: Where are u from?
opt1:Hyderabad
opt2:Secunderabad
opt3:Rajasthan
opt4:vizag

Q: What is the capital of india?
opt1: Delhi
opt2: Telangana
opt3: Madhya Pradesh
opt4: Gujrat

Q: What is 2+1?
opt1: 0
opt2: 1
opt3: 3
opt4: 6
Q: Python is a _____ language
opt1: Markup
opt2: not
opt3: programming
opt4: English
```

The above should be displayed on my testmake.html

Comment: And what did you get instead of your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The solution is documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for), and you don't need any special module or whatever:

```
<ul>
{% for q, opts in in quesBank.items %}
    <li>
        Q : {{ q  }}
        <ol> 
        {% for opt in opts %}
          <li>{{opt}}</li>        
        {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    </li>
   {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

Comment: Can we use an input radio type for the options instead of <li> ? Thanks anyways, It worked as expected

Comment: You do what you want wrt/ markup - but if you're going to build a form, do yourself (and anyone that will have to maintain this code) a favour: use a django form. FWIW, you should certainly use a proper model too instead of text file with a custom format and a half broken parser coded directly in the view.

Comment: Yeah, i was going to change it and use django forms instead. I have an other doubt with a project i am working on... check this please on my github repos https://github.com/vineethn7/taketestprojectCombined/tree/master/taketestproject

Comment: In the above mentioned repos check for Test Making app and views in that where i want to open a file in read mode that has been uploaded from Test App into media folder in the same project. Is there a way to open that file in read mode that has been just uploaded

Comment: @vineethramkumar if you have other questions, post them as new, distinct questions.